# In Power Query how do I split millions of rows into separate tables

Tags: python, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with over a million rows of information.

What I need to do, is to split that table into say rows of 1000 chunks.

I can use TopN to give me the first 1000 rows, but how do I get each subsequent 1000 rows, ie 1001-2000, 2001-3000.....

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your attempted solution and the problems you ran into. From your question it's not even clear, if you're trying this in Python or in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged python and excel formula. I know a formula won't work for you, but here is a VBA solution for you to try.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitDataToMultipleSheets()
'Declaring variables
Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long, CntRows As Long
Dim LastColumn As Integer
'Getting count of number of rows required in one sheet
CntRows = 10
'Disabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Getting row number and column number of last cell
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    'Looping through data in the sheet
    For n = 1 To LastRow Step CntRows
        'Adding new worksheet
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        'Copying data to new worksheet
        .Range("A" & n).Resize(CntRows, LastColumn).Copy Range("A1")
    Next n
    .Activate
End With
'Enabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can do something very similar in Python, but with WAY LESS CODE.

```
import pandas as pd
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('C:/your_path_here/main.csv', chunksize=10)):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i))
```

I'm not sure Power BI will do this task for you, but if someone has a solution, I'm curious to see it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Table.Split()` will accomplish what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-split

You can take any table and split it into n-size chunks of rows.